# WSO2 ESB return a string of json structures

Tags: api, wso2

I'm building an API Resource and return a string of json structures

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUC1d.png)

An error ：
wso2 com.ctc.wstx.exc.wstxunexpectedcharexception: unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<' at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]

Answer (score 0):

> enter image description here

next time please try to use formatted text here, not screenshots. You suppose to make the question easy to read for us

> unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<' at [row,col {unknown-source}]:

See the service annotation, it says @Produces Application.XML. So the service returns the `Content-Type` header as "application/xml", but the content is JSON.

The exception is saying that the ESB is trying to parse your returned XML (the service claims the content is XML) but it is not correct format